# Python inheritance parent child not equal type

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am playing with Python but am not getting the inheritance right

In my package I have User.py

```
class User(object):
  """This is the base user
    This is where all the dirty stuff happens
  """
  def __init__(self, mail=None, password=None):
    self._build({"mail": mail, "password": password, "fields": dict({})})

  def _build(self, props):
    """Private method for building objects based on dicts
    """
    props["uuid"] = uuid.uuid4()

    for k, v in props.iteritems():
      setattr(self, k, v)

  @staticmethod
  def get_or_create(**kwargs):
    """This method fetches a matching User
      or creates on based on email and password
    """
    db = utils.get_client().users

    if kwargs.get("mail") is None:
      raise ValueError("%s.mail cannot be None" % self.__class__.__name__)

    cursor = db.users.find_one({"mail": kwargs.get("mail", None)})

    if cursor is None:
      user = User()
      user._build({"mail": kwargs.get("mail", None), "password": kwargs.get("password", None)})
      user.save()
    else:
      if cursor.get("_type") == "Customer":
        user = Customer()
      else:
        user = User()

      user._build(cursor)

    return user
```

And then I have Customer.py inheriting from User

```
from gearbroker.user import User

class Customer(User):

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            User.__init__(self, mail=kwargs.get("mail", None), password=kwargs.get("password", None))
```

both in the same package at root level. My test gives me this

```
AssertionError: <class 'mypackage.user.Customer'> != <class 'mypackage.customer.Customer'>
```

when I run this test

```
  customer = Customer(mail="foo@bar.com", password="foobar")
  customer.save()

  user = User.get_or_create(mail="foo@bar.com", password="foobar")

  assert_equal(type(user), type(Customer()))
```

in this test file I import the objects like this

```
from gearbroker.user import User
from gearbroker.customer import Customer
```

How do I go about this? The customer should be a child of the User class and when comparing their type they should both be users. This was working until I decided to move the Customer and the User class into 2 different files to increase readability. Am I importing the objects wrong?

Comment: check out https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance
or https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIsInstance for assertion

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two different definitions of the `Customer` class. Your tests seems to be showing that you are getting them mixed up.

What I suspect your error comes down to is that you're wanting to refer to unqualified names `User` and `Customer` in all your modules, and you're using some kind of `from module import Name` syntax to get it. That breaks when you have circular dependencies (the `user` module needs to access the `Customer` class, but the `customer` module needs to access the `User` class).

To work around the issue, I suggest using regular `import module` statements and changing the unqualified class names to qualified versions (`user.User` and `customer.Customer`).

Or, just keep your classes both in the same module! Python isn't like Java where each class definition needs to be in its own file. If your `User` and `Customer` classes are closely bound to each other, by all means keep them in the same module!

Comment: If I change the import to import gearbroker instead of import gearbroker.user and gearbroker.customer it should work?

Comment: It's not the imports in the test that matter, but the imports in the `user` and `customer` modules. For whatever reason, the `Customer` class seen in the `user` module is not the same class that can be found in the `customer` module. Since you haven't shown those imports, I can't say specifically what's wrong or what you can do to fix things.

Comment: Added the import of user in customer

Comment: The important import is the other direction. `user` refers to `Customer`, but it doesn't seem to be getting the right class.